# Find files starting with ~$ (MicroSoft Word Temp files)

Tags: find, regular-expression

For some reason my machine is full of M$ Word temporary files such as:

```
~$Filename.docx  
~$AnotherFile.docx
```

Can someone suggest a find/regex command to search $HOME and delete them?

Comment: Typical... just figured it... `find . | egrep \~ | while read f; do mv "$f" ~/Desktop/Trash/;done`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash 4 or above:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm ~/**/'~$'*
```

In zsh or ksh93, you can use the `rm` line above directly.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to remove all files which start with `~$`:

```
find /path/to/dir -name '~$*' -delete
```